# C: do-while with scanf, multiple inputs

Tags: c

i'm trying to take a user's input and check if it is equal to some option('+','-','*','x')

```
    do {
        printf("Select the op.: ");
        scanf("%c", &option);
    } while (option != '+' || option != '-' || option != '*' || option != 'x');
    printf("%c", option);
```

This is the output:

```
Select the op.:Select the op.:Select the op.:Select the op.:
```

As you can see the `printf("Select the op.: ")` is executed multiple times and I cannot understand the reason, thus if I try to insert, eg `+`, this is the print output:

```
++
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it compile well? I see semicolon missing.

Comment: Also `option` and `operation`. Is that a typo? Did you compile the code?

Comment: yes, i have the code to another pc so i just copied it by hand, edited. By the way it compiles well ;)

Comment: No it doesn't. And still doesn't following your edit.

Comment: We are missing a semicolon again.

Comment: @Francesco: Bathsheba is pointing out that the code you compiled and the code you showed us are not the same thing. That's a really big problem if we're going to debug it for you! You are in fact required to present a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that in itself reproduces the problem. Otherwise we have no faith that you haven't made yet more "typos" when hand-copying your code here, thereby wasting our time trying to chase down a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: `&&` is the droid you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you used is always true. You should use `&&` instead of `||`. Make the truth table in order to verify it by yourself.
Why don't you use `strchr`? The condition would be more elegant:

```
do {
    printf("Select the op.: ");
    if (1 != scanf(" %c", &option)) break;
} while (!strchr("+-*x", option));
```

Also, for your other question, considering the multiple execution of the `printf` is the fact that the buffer, keeps the newline character the uses types in order to send their option to `scanf`. So in the next loop, the newline of the previous loop will be accepted by `scanf`. It is not a valid option, so, the next loop will ask you again.
You can correct it by writing `scanf` like this: `scanf(" %c", &option)`. **This works only because you know that you want to discard only one white-space character.** This is not an all-time solution.

Comment: This will fail if you hit the end of file.  You must check the return value of `scanf`: `if (scanf(" %c", &option) != 1) break;`

Answer (score 11):

```
while(option != '+' || option != '-' || option != '*' || option != 'x');
```

This condition is always true.

Answer (score 2):

Your termination condition does not what you want it to do. Try this:

```
do
{
   ...
}
while( option != '+' && option != '-' && option != '*' && option != 'x');
```

This means to continue the loop as long as `option` is not `+` and not `-` and not `*` and not `x`.

Same condition would be:

```
do
{
   ...
}
while( !( option == '+' || option == '-' || option == '*' || option == 'x' ) );
```

Apart from this check return value of `scanf`, as gon1332 does in his perfect answer.

Comment: thank you, but again i have multiple print of 'Select the op.:' before i can actually insert a input

Comment: You must also check the return value of `scanf` to avoid an infinite loop at end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Although he standards do not bless using `fflush()` on an input stream, it is documented and works on many Linux/Unix systems.  So the following may work for you, but it is not portable:

```
{
    printf("Select the op.: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &option);
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is not specified.  The C Standard says it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: which compiler your are using ?

Comment: Quoting C11 7.21.5.2 fflush: *If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*  Some compilers may attach specific behavior on `fflush(stdin)` but is remains non standard and mostly inappropriate.  Furthermore, your answer does not address the OP's problem at all.